# Is it possible to narrow down a portion of shaft to its 1/5 of its diameter?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design

I designed this shaft for my center gripper. However the slot requires to be very deep, as you can see. I want to know if it's possible to produce
this part.

The main diameter is 30 mm and the small diameter is about 5 mm.
I chose turning as the process and the material is steel.

[image]

Comment: Produce it in what? Glass? Marble? Stainless steel? Plastic? By what process? Casting? Moulding? Turning? Milling? With a diameter of 1 mm? 20 mm? 1 m? Can you see that your question is missing a ***lot*** of detail? Please [edit] the question to add the missing information.

Comment: @Transistor I edited the questions :)

Comment: I would imagine that the left end would be gripped in the chuck and the right end could be gripped in a free-wheeling tail chuck.

Comment: The diameters of 15 and 5 mm in the text don't correspond to the picture. Which one shows the correct dimensions for the part?

Comment: @alephzero Nice observation, It is indeed 30 mm

Comment: It would be easier to make this from three pieces.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the rest of the design, as this looks a very odd feature... I'd be happy to turn this with proper tail support, but as mentioned by Eric, an assembly would likely be simpler.

Comment: I think you could absolute make this. A parting tool makes this kind of cut all the time.